# Tkinter: How to set ttk.Radiobutton activated and get its value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

1) I need to set one of my three ttk.Radiobuttons activated by default
    when I start my gui app.
    How do I do it?

2) I also need to check if one of my ttk.Radiobuttons was
    activated/clicked by the user.
    How do I do it?

```
rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='5', variable=self.my_var, value=5)
rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='10', variable=self.my_var, value=10)
rb3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='15', variable=self.my_var, value=15)
self.rb1.grid(row=0)
self.rb2.grid(row=1)
self.rb3.grid(row=2)
```

Comment: If any of those answers helped you, kindly mark them as answer, it will help reduce the 'unanswered questions' line

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use `self.my_var.set(1)` to set the radiobutton with `text='5'` as the default RadioButton.

To get the selected one you have to call a function

```
rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='5', variable=self.my_var, value=5,command=self.selected)
rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='10', variable=self.my_var, value=10,command=self.selected)
rb3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frame, text='15', variable=self.my_var, value=15,command=self.selected)
self.rb1.grid(row=0)
self.rb2.grid(row=1)
self.rb3.grid(row=2)

def selected(self):
     if self.my_var.get()==5:
        "do something"
     elif self.my_var.get()==10:
        "do something"
     else:
        "do something"
```

Comment: Maybe this has changed since 2013, but to get `text='5'` you should use `self.my_var_set(5)` - it's the radiobutton's value you use for activation.
Anyway - your example is still helpful in 2021 ;-)

Answer (score 13):

As for your first question, a convenient and straightforward way is to call the `invoke` method:

```
rb2.invoke()
```

Note that this also runs any `command` associated with this button.

See the [Ttk::radiobutton invoke documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm#M11).

Comment: this was very useful!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just adding something to Gogo's answer but i can't comment because i don't have enough reputation.

Add `self.my_var=tk.IntVar()` before the radiobuttons or your program will not know the variable. see [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for more informations

for exemple, in my case i need a StringVar(): 
this works for python 3.* change `tkinter` to `Tkinter` for python 2 (i'm not 100% sure tho)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class XFile_Page(tk.Frame):
    ...

    self.joinType = tk.StringVar()
    self.rbLeft = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frameRadioButtons, text='left', variable=self.joinType, value='left',command=self.RadioBtnSelected)
    self.rbRight = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frameRadioButtons, text='right', variable=self.joinType, value='right',command=self.RadioBtnSelected)

    self.rbLeft.grid(row=0)
    self.rbRight.grid(row=1)

    #select the rbLeft radiobutton
    self.rbLeft.invoke()

    def RadioBtnSelected(self):
        print(self.joinType.get())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rb1.state['selected']` to set the default as `rb1` and `self.my_var.get()` to get the value (i.e the text variable) of the radiobutton.